# Why does it say the requestCode in PendingIntent.getBroadcast() is not used?

Tags: android

The [documentation for `PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) states that in the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, the `requestCode` parameter is "currently not used." However, I did some pretty exhaustive testing and setting different `requestCode`s quite clearly alters the behavior of the program (and setting different `requestCode`s seems to be a commonly accepted approach to differentiating Intents for alarms).

Is the fact that `requestCode` quite clearly is used a bug that's at risk of being "fixed?" Or can I keep using it to differentiate my PendingIntents?

Some background:

I set up a test app with the following code for `onCreate` in my main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("text", "text one");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
    time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("text", "text two");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

as well as a very simple AlarmReceiver:

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("text"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Then I experimented with setting different flags and requestCodes for the PendingIntents. These are the results:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqelXkzmAL0dDNYeVEyekJyRkV1VDZNVVIyQTJkdmc#gid=0

Comment: My guess is the documentation is out of date, or that the uses you described aren't what the android engineers had in mind for that feature, but are still valid. In any case, I sincerely doubt any changes they make will break this kind of use case. You could try filing a report at http://b.android.com and seeing what someone from Google says about it

Comment: @RaghavSood the documentation is unlikely to be out of date (Last updated on March 21st, looks like) but yeah, I'm not TOO concerned, it's mostly an academic curiosity. :) I might file a report, thanks (although in my experience they're not exactly responsive).

Comment: They don't always update every single method description :P The documentation falls out of date in bits and pieces quite often.

Comment: @RaghavSood Fair enough, can't argue with that.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)  "Private request code for the sender" here it comes guys.

Answer (score 1):

`requestCode` is most definitely used and has been for quite some time. Android documentation is out of date and has been for quite a while as well. Check AOSP source to confirm if you want.